# Finding the root cause of getting invalid pc load usage hard fault [STM32]

Tags: stm32, embedded

So I am playing around with UART by setting different baud rates at the RX/TX ends (9600 vs 19200), and I see sending data from serial causes a hardfault. When I checked into the respective memory, I see `INVPC` (Invalid PC load usage fault) is set -> the whole `CFSR` has a value of `00040000`.

any way I can narrow down the root cause?

**edit:**

MCU: STM32F401 NUCLEO

i also see `HardFault Status Register (HFSR)` having `00000040`. Not sure why considering it's a reserved bit.

[image]

Code snippet:

```
char rx_buffer[20] = {0};
USART usart;

void parse_serial(USART *usart, char *temp_buffer, char *rx_buffer) {
    char *start = rx_buffer;
    char *end = strstr(rx_buffer, "\r");
    uint8_t bytes = end - start;
    memcpy(temp_buffer, start, bytes);
}

void receive_serial(USART *usart)
{
    while (USART_receive_data(USART_RX_BUSY) != USART_READY);
}

void serial_session(USART *usart, char *rx_buffer){
    char temp_buffer[usart->rx_size] = {0}; // null-defined
    while(true) {
      receive_serial(usart); 
      parse_serial (usart, temp_buffer, rx_buffer);
      // do something with parsed data
    }
}

void usart_init(USART *usart, char *rx_buffer, uint8_t rx_size...) {
    usart->rxBuffer = rx_buffer;
    usart->rx_size = rx_size;
    ...
    usart_init(usart);
} 

int main(void) {
   usart_init(&usart, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer)/sizeof(rx_buffer[0]),...);
   serial_session(usart, rx_buffer);
   while(1);
}
 // note: passing `rx_buffer` to `serial_session()` cause I no longer have access to the start of the array since the pointer inside the ISR for storing bytes off `DR` kept incrementing for each byte.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109280/discussion-on-question-by-xyf-finding-the-root-cause-of-getting-invalid-pc-load).

Answer (score 0):

Check the interrupt vector table. There probably is a bad irq pointer.

Comment: you mean in the startup file?

Answer (score 0):

Receive data into ring buffer, and from there copy only data that is received into a working edit buffer, and only react on the working buffer when \r is received. In the ring buffer there are no null-retminated strings. If you must, zero the buffer or write an extra \0 so that there is a null, but that is a kludge.

Comment: I still don't see how what I have is causing an issue that a circular buffer would solve...

Comment: Again, you must not call string functions on raw buffers that do not contain a terminating null!  This is basic to C programming and a common way to crash

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed circular buffer for reception, because I don't know what kind of buffer you have. Yes, your problem is not solved by a circular reception buffer. You must not write past the buffer, and you can simply react on the \r character when it comes in.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I think you're under the wrong assumption. I have posted my code which hopefully clears out that i'm not using a raw buffer without null character.

Comment: Your claim of null initialization is in fact utterly false, because what you are initializing is an entirely different buffer than what you are improperly running a string function on.  There is no sanity to the design of this code at all, it's just a mess of disjoint and incompatible pieces thrown towards a wall.